# Slide to reveal a view like NotificationCenter/Twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to mimic Twitter's "slide up to show" action as soon in the attached images: [image: First View with Detailed View Hidden][image: Detail View Visible After Sliding Up]

If you notice the detail view is hidden in the first with just a little indicator there's more there. Then when you slide up it shows the detail view. I don't want to slide the main view away, just detect the touch and slide up then "move" the hidden view into view.

I'm thinking something like instantiating the view with a frame that is off screen. Then when the user slides it will reframe to be on screen. I cannot figure out how to animate it so it starts to appear with the slide. Any tips? Does this approach seem like a good way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try out this,
Initially keep the details view off the screen then use the following code to bring it up by giving the co-ordinates

```
CGRect detailsViewFrame = detailsView.frame;
detailsViewFrame.origin.x = 222; // new x coordinate
detailsViewFrame.origin.y = 294; // new y coordinate

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.2 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         detailsView.frame = detailsViewFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
```

Comment: I will play around with this. The opensource project linked by @Pavan Kris implements exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this
https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView.

That view provides details on pulldown , pullup view.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I figured there was a project but I couldn't think of "pullable" to find it